# SSH: accept connection with password only from localhost

Tags: ssh, config, sshd

I want to be able to connect to root@localhost with a password and from the outside (root@my-ip) with a private key only. I didn't find what to write in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to allow this… If it requires both an SSH key and a password it's ok too.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your openssh version, but in recent ones, you can set up:

```
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
Match LocalAddress 127.0.0.1,::1  # localhost
  PermitRootLogin yes
```

Or using some other equivalent that is supported by your version (`PasswordAuthentication`).

Comment: It works with: Match LocalAddress 127.0.0.1,::1 :-) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the note about IPv6. I always forget :)